# Bluetooth paired device in range event

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm looking for an event triggered when my phone discovers an already-paired device...

Example: a door has a bluetooth lock. When I come home, I want the lock to be open. When I leave my home I want the lock to be closed.
In order to achieve these features I need to find an event triggered when an already-paired device is in the range of my phone...

Obviously I dont want to use my phone manually to lock/unlock the door. The operation must be automatic.

It is possible to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a solution to this problem.
Unfortunately it seems not to be possible for every device.

I'm using:

```
  <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
```

which works for devices that actively try to connect (like Headsets or my LG G Watch).

For devices that require you to connect to them this is not working.

Only solution I've found so far is to poll the known adress in a background service or with AlamrManager.